# What's the best way to design the web interface which runs the same on almost all resolutions?

Tags: layout, css

With web pages, what's the CSS framework or any other idea, which may show the web pages the same way on almost all screen resolution using div?

Comment: You can't exactly, but you can use Responsive Web Design to make it look good in each resolution.

Answer (score 4):

I think he wants to know whether to choose Fixed, Fluid or Elastic.

Check out the following:
http://green-beast.com/blog/?p=199

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have separate css files for each size you will never make everyone happy.

You can't make a design that will work well on an iPhone and a projector.

What you can do is check the user-agent and have separate views for different types of devices or you can build a flexible css design using % and have it work ***pretty well*** on most machines.